# How to extract value from json

Tags: php, json

I have this json

```
{"response":{"status":"SUCCESS","totalsent":1,"cost":2}}
```

Now I want to extract the value of "status"

Please how can I do this in php?

Answer (score 1):

```
$yourJson = '{"response":{"status":"SUCCESS","totalsent":1,"cost":2}}';
$jsArr = json_decode($yourJson, true);
print_r($jsArr['response']['status']);
```